# Populate datagrid from two tables (VB.NET / Access)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, datagrid, vba

I have Access database and I'm using VB.NET. DB has two tables

1. Technicians
2. Faults

I have columns I want from technicians table in datagrid, but I want to have extra column which should show how many faults every technician fixed based on the Faults table(so I think query will need to run for every row). Is this even possible?

Big Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be

```
SELECT technicians.techname, count(*) AS NoOfFaults
FROM technicians
LEFT JOIN faults ON technicians.ID = faults.TechnicianID
GROUP BY technicians.techname;
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct on SQL but my main problem is how to insert that NoOfFaults to that extra or custom column in datagrid...

Comment: how are you binding your existing query to the grid? You can change the query

Comment: This is in onLoad() Me.TechniciansTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MainDBDataSet1.Technicians) I wrote no query yet.

Comment: You should have provided this information in the question. That would make answering your question easier

Comment: I figured it out, what you said is right but I also had to enable AutoGenerateColumns property of DataGrid to true so it added column for NoOfFaults which was what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify which columns you want to add in the form's Load() method and enable autogenerate columns property for gridview to true.